# How can I drop duplicate rows from a Polars DataFrame according to a custom function?

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a dataframe where I am trying to remove all duplicates in a specific column while aggregating the non-duplicated values.

The `.unique` function lets me choose only one of `{‘first’, ‘last’, ‘any’, ‘none’}`. However what I want is to apply the `mean` function to all numeric values, and the `mode` function to all categorical values.

I can do this by using `groupby` on the column I'm interested in, like in the example below:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        "color": ["red", "green", "green", "red", "red"],
        "shape": ["square", "triangle", "square", "triangle", "square"],
        "size": [2, 4, 6, 1, 3]
    }
)

df_list = []
for gkey, group in df.groupby("id"):
    g = group.select(pl.col("id"),
       pl.all().exclude("id", "size").mode().first(),
       pl.col("size").mean()
    ).unique()
    df_list.append(g)

df_dedup = pl.concat(df_list)
```

Which gives me the output I'm expecting:

```
> print(df_dedup)
shape: (2, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬──────────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ color ┆ shape    ┆ size │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str      ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ red   ┆ triangle ┆ 2.0  │
│ 0   ┆ green ┆ square   ┆ 4.0  │
└─────┴───────┴──────────┴──────┘
```

The problem is that this implementation is (unsurprisingly) quite slow, so I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this, or if it's possible to optimize the code I have in some way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```py
In [22]: df.groupby("id").agg(
    ...:     pl.col(["color", "shape"]).mode().sort(descending=True).first(),
    ...:     pl.col("size").mean(),
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[22]:
shape: (2, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬──────────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ color ┆ shape    ┆ size │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str      ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ red   ┆ triangle ┆ 2.0  │
│ 0   ┆ green ┆ square   ┆ 4.0  │
└─────┴───────┴──────────┴──────┘
```

Or, using the column selectors:

```py
In [30]: import polars.selectors as cs

In [31]: df.groupby("id").agg(
    ...:     cs.string().mode().sort(descending=True).first(),
    ...:     cs.numeric().mean(),
    ...: )
Out[31]:
shape: (2, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬──────────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ color ┆ shape    ┆ size │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str      ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════════╪══════╡
│ 0   ┆ green ┆ square   ┆ 4.0  │
│ 1   ┆ red   ┆ triangle ┆ 2.0  │
└─────┴───────┴──────────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Both work and are way faster than my solution, so thanks for that! Just one note on the first method: the selection can't contain the column that is being used for grouping (`id` in this case), otherwise an error is raised. That threw me off until I noticed what was happening. The second method does not have that problem. Just making sure people are aware!

Answer (score 2):

You can select columns by type, e.g. `pl.col(pl.Utf8)` for all `str` columns.

There's also the new [`polars.selectors` helper module.](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html)

```
import polars.selectors as cs

df.groupby('id').agg(
   cs.string().mode().first(),
   cs.numeric().mean()
)
```

```
shape: (2, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬──────────┬──────┐
│ id  ┆ color ┆ shape    ┆ size │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---  │
│ i64 ┆ str   ┆ str      ┆ f64  │
╞═════╪═══════╪══════════╪══════╡
│ 1   ┆ red   ┆ triangle ┆ 2.0  │
│ 0   ┆ green ┆ square   ┆ 4.0  │
└─────┴───────┴──────────┴──────┘
```

Comment: The `selectors` module looks really useful, and this solved the problem